# How can back to scene from view?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Ques: I had added the view using the code:

[[[Director sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:myView];

But how can I will back to Game scene?

if you are asking how to attach UIKit views and such to a cocos2d-iphone project, you just have to do it like:

[[[Director sharedDirector] window] addSubview:myView];

Updated to cocos 0.7 and now this is:

[[[Director sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:myView];

Comment: sorry, a bit incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

How about just removing your view?

```
[myView removeFromSuperview];
```